# get the userid of a user onCreate and update db

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a cloud function that detects when a new user has been created using the oncreate((user) function and then add the value of 50 to the points field. 
This is what gets created:

[image: User]

What i'm trying to do is to just detect when the user is created, get the ID and change the points value to 50, it must be a cloud function. 
This is what my code currently looks like.

```
    exports.updatepoints = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

  const userID = firebase.auth.currentUser.uid; 
  return updatepoints(userID)
});

async function updatepoints(userID) {
  return firebase.database().ref('mobile_user/' + userID).set(
    {
      points: 50
    });
};
```

I am fairly new to JS and firebase so any help of guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What is the identifier `firebase` here?  If you're trying to use the javascript client library in Cloud Functions, that's not the right way to go.  You need to use the admin SDK instead.  Also, you may want to start at the documentation for auth triggers, because you will need to understand what that `user` parameter is.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

Comment: FYI your `async` is superfluous

Comment: Are the users created client side (JavaScript/Web SDK) or server side with the Admin/Node SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

First i would change the name of the function to really say what the function is doing, in this case initializing a user.  So initUser.

Then your functions receive data in form of user.  Use that to get infos on the created user and save the data to Firebase.

Something like this should work.

```
import { auth } from 'firebase-functions';
import { database } from 'firebase-admin';

exports.initUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

const mobileUser = {
email: user.email,
points: 50,
subscribedToMailingList: true
}    

const ref = database().ref(`mobile_user/${user.uid}`);

  return ref.set(mobileUser)
    .then(() => console.log(`Created user: ${user.email}`))
    .catch((error) => console.log(`Error: ${error}`));
```

Comment: IMHO you should return the promise returned by `set()` like `return ref.set(mobileUser)....`.  More details in the official video series https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/, in particular "Learn JavaScript Promises (Pt. 2) with a Firestore Trigger in Cloud Functions"